# Change psql copy command with dynamic headers

Tags: linux, shell, psql

I have following working copy command:

```
export PGPASSWORD=****;psql -h "****" -U "****" -c "\copy (SELECT id, \"accountType\" as \"ACCOUNT TYPE\", \"actReasonCode\" as \"ACT REASON\",\"adrCity\" as \"ADR CITY\" FROM schemaName.\"tableName\" where id > 0 and id<=8238226) TO STDOUT CSV HEADER" dbName >/sourcefile/test.CSV
```

Now,  Instead giving alias name in the query,my requirement is to get the header as input and append it in the copy command, something like below:

```
export PGPASSWORD=****;psql -h "****" -U "****" -c "\copy (SELECT id, \"accountType\", \"actReasonCode\",\"adrCity\" FROM schemaName.\"tableName\" where id > 0 and id<=8238226) TO STDOUT CSV HEADERS(ID,\"ACCOUNT TYPE\",\"ACT REASON\",\"ADR CITY\") " dbName >/sourcefile/test.CSV
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you include any error messages you receive when running the second command?

Comment: @LucasRamage Thanks for your reply. Am getting the following error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "HEADERS"
LINE 1: ...re id > 0 and id<=8238226 ) TO STDOUT  CSV HEADER HEADERS(ID...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Don't tell us only what didn't work. Tell us about the problem itself.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I want to get the header name as separate input and append it to the command. I don't want to have alias name in the query, because client will pass header values like ID|ACCOUNT TYPE|ACT REASON|ADR CITY.So I want to generate CSV file with the custom header

Comment: I am going to assume your user input is well sanitised and safe and contains four comma separated, valid names. In that case you can write that line to the output file first using a simple `echo a,b,c,d > /sourcefile/test.csv` and later on append to that file using a double arrow instead, e.g. `... dbName >> /sourcefile/test.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have misunderstood the HEADER keyword.

> HEADER [boolean]
>
> Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the column names from the table, and on input, the first line is ignored. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html

As you can see, the option allows you to enable or disable the printing of a header line. It is not meant to be used to select which columns to print. That is part of your SELECT in the beginning of your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anyway to give the header names

Comment: @kaviya.P when you say you want to give the "header names" I guess you mean the first line in the output. That line is composed of the things you select "AS". E.g. if you select "accountType" as "ACCOUNT TYPE", what your CSV file is going to show on top is "ACCOUNT TYPE". You can change that right-hand part to whatever you like.